# Environment health has transitioned from Ok to Severe. ELB health is failing or not available for all instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to deploy my Docker container to AWS beanstalk but after initialisation the health goes from ok to severe, I'm new to AWS so i'm not fully aware of whats going on.

- **LOGS:** https://drive.google.com/file/d/1i8GgfP7pI-57Uz8J6UTFq6Q4kHxXcXfC/view?usp=sharing

**.elasticbeanstalk**

```
branch-defaults:
  default:
    environment: Sentiment-App-env
    group_suffix: null
global:
  application_name: Sentiment-App
  branch: null
  default_ec2_keyname: null
  default_platform: Docker
  default_region: eu-west-3
  include_git_submodules: true
  instance_profile: null
  platform_name: null
  platform_version: null
  profile: eb-cli
  repository: null
  sc: null
  workspace_type: Application
```

When i try to access it using its link given after environment is launched. It gives error with

```
text = {"text" : "Hello how are you"}

response = requests.post(url, json=text)

response.json
```

But when i remove .json from the response the output i get is:

```
<Response [503]>
```

The commands that are used on the elastic beanstalk CLI are:

*eb init -p docker Sentiment-App*

*eb local run --port 5000*

*eb create Sentiment-App-env*

I thought the local images of docker are causing issues because of :

```
2022/11/17 09:07:00.176214 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c docker rmi `docker images -aq`
2022/11/17 09:07:00.309532 [INFO] Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to delete f0cfeb300221 (cannot be forced) - image is being used by running container 592def234eec
Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to delete e86cc458ba3e (cannot be forced) - image has dependent child images
Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to delete c84b9f0e15ae (cannot be forced) - image has dependent child images
Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to delete 14d1c8d785fb (cannot be forced) - image has dependent child images
Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to delete 85ddbde6e40b (cannot be forced) - image has dependent child images
Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to delete a47d88688a61 (cannot be forced) - image has dependent child images
Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to delete 465483cdaa4e (cannot be forced) - image has dependent child images
```

So i deleted all images that were there locally and all local containers, again created environment same issue.

The docker image is working well, i checked multiple times. Its giving response and the right response. Everything that goes wrong is while creating the AWS evironment.